# How to get data in ListView depends on user?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, listview

How to get data from mysql database in ListView based on user logged in. Below is the Json i am getting:

```
{"android":[{"username":"lokesh","company":"ffff","client":"xyz","client_no":"5487968475","callback":"2016-12-29 11:30:00"},
    {"username":"Rahul","company":"yyyy","client":"Suresh","client_no":"5789486589","callback":"2016-12-16 15:14:00"},
    {"username":"Fayaz","company":"ddddd","client":"Haresh","client_no":"4444889955","callback":"2016-12-28 14:00:00"},
    {"username":"Rahul","company":"qqqqq","client":"gore","client_no":"4444889955","callback":"2016-12-28 14:00:00"}]}
```

Here, I am getting above Json which is complete data  present in database, I am getting all 4 entries in listview but what i really want is if i logged into app by username of Rahul then i should able to see only 2 records. If i logged in as Fayaz then i should able to see only 1 record in listview. Can anyone help me in that.. Below are my code:
Activity:

```
public class AboutUsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoadJSONTask.Listener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView mListView;


public static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/android/get.php";
private List<HashMap<String, String>> mAndroidMapList = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String KEY_COMPANY = "company";
private static final String KEY_CLIENT = "client";
private static final String KEY_CLIENT_NO = "client_no";
private static final String KEY_CALLBACK = "callback";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    new LoadJSONTask(this).execute(URL);
}

@Override
public void onLoaded(List<AndroidVersion> androidList) {

    for (AndroidVersion android : androidList) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(KEY_COMPANY, android.getCompany());
        map.put(KEY_CLIENT, android.getClient());
        map.put(KEY_CLIENT_NO, android.getClient_no());
        map.put(KEY_CALLBACK, android.getCallback());

        mAndroidMapList.add(map);
    }

    loadListView();
}

@Override
public void onError() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    Toast.makeText(this, mAndroidMapList.get(i).get(KEY_CLIENT_NO),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void loadListView() {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AboutUsActivity.this, mAndroidMapList, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_COMPANY, KEY_CLIENT, KEY_CLIENT_NO, KEY_CALLBACK },
            new int[] { R.id.company,R.id.client, R.id.client_no,R.id.callback });

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

LoadJSONTask Class:

```
public class LoadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response> {

public LoadJSONTask(Listener listener) {

    mListener = listener;
}

public interface Listener {

    void onLoaded(List<AndroidVersion> androidList);

    void onError();
}

private Listener mListener;

@Override
protected Response doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {

        String stringResponse = loadJSON(strings[0]);
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        return gson.fromJson(stringResponse, Response.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {

    if (response != null) {

        mListener.onLoaded(response.getAndroid());

    } else {

        mListener.onError();
    }
}

private String loadJSON(String jsonURL) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(jsonURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        response.append(line);
    }

    in.close();
    return response.toString();
}
}
```

PHP FIle:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM meetdetails";
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$android = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
array_push($android,array(
    'username'=>$row['username'],
    'company'=>$row['company_name'],
    'client'=>$row['client_name'],
    'client_no'=>$row['client_no'],
    'callback'=>$row['callback']
));
}

echo json_encode(array('android'=>$android));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can either send the user name to your server where they  will provide you the user specific request but that also you have  to ask them to implemet like this. or create HasmMap> to store user specific data in hasmap where KEY of hasmap should be either username or user_id and then you can use get method to get the specific user data from hasmap.

Comment: can you give any example? It will be big help Ma'am

Answer (score 0):

Save your SQL result in a general var and before creating the ListView filter the data based on the username.
For each signed in user name the filter will represent only his data.

Other option is to filter the dada inside the adapter, again based on the connected user name hide the irrelevant items.